# Given a number $N$, count all the ways to split $N$, so that each part is at most $K$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find an algorithm to do this, this is what I have so far:

We know that the total number of ways to split a number $N$ is $2^{n-1}$, where $n$ is the number of digits of that number $N$.

Knowing this, we can try to find all invalid ways of splitting the number and subtracting from the total, I did it by a recursive approach. It worked however is a bit slow.

I am looking to solve this problem for really large numbers like $10^{100}$ without waiting an eternity.

Example: For $N = 123, K = 8$, we have four ways to split $123$: $123, 1-23, 12-3, 1-2-3$ since $k = 8$, only the last one is valid.

Answer: 1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dynamic programming approach. Let $f_i$ be the number of ways to split number formed by first $i$ digits in such a way that all the parts are less or equal than $K$. It's easy to see that $f_i = \sum f_j$ over such $j$, that number formed with digits from $j + 1$-th to $i$-th is less or equal than $K$. This algorithm is polynomial on the length of input (naive implementation is $O(n^3)$ but algorithm can be implemented even in $O(n \log n)$ time) and will work for numbers of order $10^{100}$ fast on modern PC.

Comment: Can you give me more details on how calculating works?